# Understanding proof for convergence of Taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(x-c)^n \qquad \qquad(1)$

**Theorem:** Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be open interval, $c\in I$ and $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f\in C^{\infty}(I)$. If there exist $n_0\in \mathbb{N}, \delta \gt 0, M\gt 0$ and $C\gt 0$, such that $$|f^{(n)}(x)|\le CM^nn!,\quad \forall x\in I'=\langle c- \delta,c + \delta\rangle \cap I,\quad \forall n\ge n_0$$

then $(1)$ converges to $f(x)$, $\forall x \in I' \cap \langle c- \frac1{M},c + \frac1{M} \rangle$.

**Proof:**

For every $x\in I$, by Taylor theorem, there exists $c_x$ between $x$ and $c$ such that $$f(x)=T_n(x)+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c_x)}{(n+1)!} (x-c)^{n+1}$$

From here we have

$$|f(x)-T_n(x)| = \frac{|f^{(n+1)}(c_x)|}{(n+1)!}|x-c|^{n+1}\le C\frac{M^{n+1}(n+1)!}{(n+1)!}|x-c|^{n+1}=C(M|x-c|)^{n+1}$$

For $x\in I' \cap \langle c-\frac1{M},c+ \frac1{M} \rangle$ is $M|x-c|\lt 1$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty}|f(x)-T_n(x)|=0$.

Hence, $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} T_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n=f(x) $$

My question is this: $c_x$ doesn't have to be from $I'$, so why is this ok:

$$\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(c_x)|}{(n+1)!}|x-c|^{n+1}\le C\frac{M^{n+1}(n+1)!}{(n+1)!}|x-c|^{n+1}$$

Is there a mistake in theorem?

Comment: $c_x$ lies between $c$ and $x$. Whenever $x\in I'$, then also $c_x \in I'$.

Comment: Yes , but here we have $x \in I$

Comment: Oh. That's just a typo, it should have been $x \in I'$. The Taylor series need not converge to $f$ outside of $I'$ under the given assumptions.

Comment: Okay, thanks, my book has many typos like that